# Ajax and rewrite engine

Tags: javascript, ajax, .htaccess

I have a problem with ajax and rewrite engin. I made a site, where I use this load more script:

> http://www.9lessons.info/2009/12/twitter-style-load-more-results-with.html

Everything works fine on users profile page (I am getting posts from users feedback), when the url looks like this: **example.com/user.php?u=ExampleUser**
but I have this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^u/(.*) user.php?u=$1 [L]
```

So if I type something like **example.com/u/ExampleUser** I get the username like:

```
$username = $_GET['u'];
```

But in this way when I click on the load more it doesn't load more posts from the user, it just starts to lead the site itself to the div box (like it is an iframe...).
Please help me, it is necessary.
Here is my script, which should load more info from MySQL database($id is userid from DB):

```
$(function() {
    // More Button
    $('.more').live("click",function() {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        if (ID) {
            $("#more" + ID).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_more.php",
                data: 'lastmsg='+ID+'&user='+<? echo $id; ?>,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#container").append(html);
                    $("#more"+ID).remove();
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(".morebox").html('The End');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: at what moment your problem was PHP or MySQL related that you tagged it that way?

Comment: Ok, sorry, tags were removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing the entire context of your code, it *looks* like when the ajax call is made, the final url is something along the lines of `domain.tld/u/ajax_more.php`.

I get around this issue by maintaining a list of constants in the javascript object.

For example, I have a `paths.php` file that contains this:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
    echo "
        myNamespace.paths = {
            RELATIVE_FOLDER: '<?=RELATIVE_FOLDER?>',
            // add more as required...
        }
    ";
?>
```

This is included in the page just like a regular script (with `script` tags), and from that point forward, `myNamespace.paths` will contain your constants, as returned by the server.

In my case, if the URL was "http://www.example.org/path/to/my/dev/env", I would have `RELATIVE_FOLDER` set to `/path/to/my/dev/env/` on the server-side, which would then be included into the paths object.

Later, in your ajax calls:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myNamespace.paths.RELATIVE_FOLDER + "ajax_more.php",
    // ... everything else
});
```

---

I notice you have no problem with directly injecting PHP into your scripts. This is not necessarily a bad thing, but it does make it harder for you to minify your js. This is the reason why I went with a separate file to store the constants, instead of directly injecting it into the javascript itself with `<?= ... ?>` tags.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I was working on this for hours... Works fine, but I used this script: http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/how-to-get-the-base-url-with-javascript

Comment: Btw the php script did not worked for me, it just wrote out the whole source code.

Comment: Hi Markl, what was the error? Keep in mind `RELATIVE_FOLDER` is not a pre-defined constant. You must define it in PHP (either in the script or in a separate included file) with `define('RELATIVE_FOLDER', '/path/to/folder');`

Comment: Of course I know, but it looks like I have syntax error somewhere, because it looks like a " is missing somewhere, but did not find it yet.

Comment: I see, best of luck! Let me know if I can help. Perhaps myNamespace (or whatever your namespace is called) is not defined?